# Cookies not sent to server when logged in through a subdomain

Tags: php, zend-framework, subdomain, session-cookies

I have a website www.example.com
When a user logs in when he visits http://example.com and then when he browses http://www.example.com, he is shown as NOT logged in. I think the reason is that the cookies set when he visited http://example are not being sent to the server when the same user visits http://www.example.com

I want the user to be shown as logged in in both of the sites if he logs in any one of the sites. I have a mobile site also http://m.example.com. I want the user to be shown as logged in here also.

I am using PHP and Zend Framework for my web application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the cookie domain (5th arg of set_cookie) to ".example.com".

http://php.net/set_cookie

> The domain that the cookie is
>   available to. **To make the cookie
>   available on all subdomains of
>   example.com (including example.com
>   itself) then you'd set it to
>   '.example.com'**. Although some browsers
>   will accept cookies without the
>   initial ., » RFC 2109 requires it to
>   be included. Setting the domain to
>   'www.example.com' or
>   '.www.example.com' will make the
>   cookie only available in the www
>   subdomain.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

set it in php.ini

```
 session.cookie_domain = .example.com
```

OR

```
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".example.com");
```

This will alive session in sub domain also.